# MySQL Multiple lines string puts 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a multiple line string into my MySQL db.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `dressuurpaardje`.`Marks` (`markID`, `testID`, `markPosition`, `techinicalMark`, `directiveIdeas`, `maxMark`, `coefficient`, `overflow`) 
VALUES (NULL, 1, 'M', 'Proceed in passage ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + ' Transition collected walk - passage', NULL, 10, NULL, NULL);
```

I use `' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + '` with the intention to get a newline in the string. But this puts the string "0" in my db

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `CONCAT()` function for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use '\n' in your query, and let the text interpreter add the line (depends what you use, but that's what I would recommend)
2. Use `CONCAT(string1, CHAR(10), CHAR(13), string2)`, as mentionned also by Mazatwork.

Be aware that CHAR10 + CHAR13 is wrong. A line feed / carriage return is either:

- chr10 or \n (unix)
- chr13 + chr10 or \r\n (windows)

Comment: I did use \n in the first place but i put it in the string. Should i use `CONCAT(string1, \n, string2)` or 'string1 \n string2'

Comment: it depends on your interpreter. For example an html textarea understands \n natively in the string. But anyway if you decide using it you should put it in the string directly. Since mysql uses \ to escape characters maybe you'll have to insert \\n instead.

Comment: String are used in a twigg file and use `|nl2br` to interpret the newlines.

Comment: what is it? what's the ascii code of this? Then that's what you should insert I think...

Comment: There's a third option, of using `||` as an infix concatenation operator, but only if the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) SQL mode is enabled.

Comment: Since we use html/twigg i opted to use `<br \>` to insert newlines it's a dirty fix until i got a better solution. Since i'm prototyping on a windows machine with wamp and it will be run on a linux machine if operational

Comment: linux won't change anything if the application hardcodes its own line feeds. Inserting <br> will be just fine then.